# Match the nodes in xml to Entity framework class

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, reflection

I have a sql server DB with bunch of tables in it.  In one table called `orders` I have about 20 fields of various types.  Every night, I get this xml file that I'm support to parse and insert in the table.  The problem is that the xml snippet for the `order` node is always a subset of the number of columns that I have in that table.  In one node, I can have 4 fields.  Yet, in another node (same xml file), I can 9 fields.  But again, the xml `order` node is always a subset of the columns that I have in the `orders` table.

Now I can theoretically layout all the 20 fields and match them one by one to the xml file regardless whether I have that element or not.  And if I don't, I can wrap the darn thing in `try/catch` and set it to `null` in catch block if the element doesn't exists.  But that's so 90's.  Is there a `dynamic` way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the XML structure reflect (theoretically if complete) the table schema you can import the table schema using Linq2Sql that create a class for representing your table.

So you can create a Datacontext to connect to you database, and deserialize your XML directly over your table entry entity.
If the XML does not meet right name to use a directly deserialization you can manipulate it using regex and string replace.
If a field is missing in will be ignored during deserialization (remain null in your entity).

```
    public static XElement XmlSerialize(object obj, bool returnNullOnError = false)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            StringWriter stream = new StringWriter();
            serializer.Serialize(stream, obj);

            XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(stream.ToString());

            return xml.Root;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (returnNullOnError)
                return null;
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static object DeSerialize(XElement xmlSerialized, Type objectType)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType);
        XDocument d = new XDocument(xmlSerialized);
        object obj = null;

        using (XmlReader r = d.CreateReader())
        {
            obj = serializer.Deserialize(r);
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will give it a try.  Any good reference and perhaps code snippet as to how to serialized the xml to EF?  Thanks Skary

Comment: @Zuzlx let me know if the ansewr meets your requirements

Comment: Sorry about the delay.  I was on vacation for a few days and today got back.  I will give this a try and will let you know.  Thanks Skary!!

Comment: I had to take a different way of doing this but I give you the points for the help.